# lookup columns in sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, lookup, custom-lists

how do I reference lists with columns in a parent site which I want to look up from a subsite of a different parent site?

how is this done?

Answer (score 0):

Check the [SharePoint Filtered Lookup Field](http://filteredlookup.codeplex.com/) project at CodePlex and don't let the name fool you - one of the features is: *Cross-site lookup (all sites within same site collection)*.